# GCM Registration token in iOS

Tags: ios, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am completely new to GCM integration with iOS i have an *GCMSENDERID* all i want to get registration token with this sender id.The function is also not getting called.let me know what mistake i have done or please give me some examples to sort it out.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

    static NSString *const INSTANCE_ID_REGISTRATION_NOTIF_KEY = @"instance-id-token";
    static NSString *const GCM_SENDER_ID = @"19398749911";

    @interface AppDelegate ()
    {
    }
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *registrationOptions;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) GGLInstanceIDTokenHandler registrationHandler;

    @end

    @implementation AppDelegate

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes=(UIUserNotificationTypeSound|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings=[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]registerForRemoteNotifications];

        self.registrationHandler = ^(NSString *registrationToken, NSError *error){
            if (registrationToken != nil) {
                //I do get the token, and I can store it
                NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                [defaults setObject:registrationToken forKey:INSTANCE_ID_REGISTRATION_NOTIF_KEY];
                NSLog(@"Registration Token: %@", registrationToken);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Registration to GCM failed with error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
            }
        };

        return YES;

    }

    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
        // Start the GGLInstanceID shared instance with the default config and request a registration
        // token to enable reception of notifications
        NSLog(@"didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken");
        [[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] startWithConfig:[GGLInstanceIDConfig defaultConfig]];
        self.registrationOptions = @{kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
                                     kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:@NO};//I tried both YES and NO value
        [[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:GCM_SENDER_ID
                                                            scope:kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM
                                                          options:self.registrationOptions
                                                          handler:self.registrationHandler];
    }

    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err {
        NSLog(@"Error in registration. Error: %@", err);
    }

    - (void)onTokenRefresh {
        // A rotation of the registration tokens is happening, so the app needs to request a new token.
        NSLog(@"The GCM registration token needs to be changed.");
        [[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:GCM_SENDER_ID
                                                            scope:kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM
                                                          options:self.registrationOptions
                                                          handler:self.registrationHandler];
    }

    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))handler {
        NSLog(@"Notification received: %@", userInfo);//This log never prints so the method is never called
        // This works only if the app started the GCM service
        [[GCMService sharedInstance] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];
        // Handle the received message
        // Invoke the completion handler passing the appropriate UIBackgroundFetchResult value
        // ...
    }


    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
        NSLog(@"Notification received: %@", userInfo);//This log never prints so the method is never called
        // This works only if the app started the GCM service
        [[GCMService sharedInstance] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];
        // Handle the received message
        // Invoke the completion handler passing the appropriate UIBackgroundFetchResult value
        // ...
    }

    - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
        // Connect to the GCM server to receive non-APNS notifications
        [[GCMService sharedInstance] connectWithHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Could not connect to GCM: %@", error.localizedDescription);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Connected to GCM");
                // ...
            }
        }];
    }
```

Comment: Which method is not getting called?

Comment: If you are talking about this method: `didReceiveRemoteNotification`, it will only be invoked when you receive a notification. When you register and if its successful, the log should print the Registration token for the device.

Comment: Other than that, `kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:@NO};` //I tried both YES and NO value - not accurate as this method has a purpose. You use YES if its a development build and NO if its production and you need  certificate and provisioning profile set up accordingly as well.